Show that the number $a_{2n}*a_{2n+1}$ is a perfect square, for any $n \geq 1$
The problem
Consider the string $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ defined by $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1}=[\frac{n^2}{a_n}]$ for any $n\geq $1. Show that the number $a_{2n}*a_{2n+1}$ is a perfect square, for any $n \geq 1$
my idea
I thought of using mathematical induction.
First we calculated $a_1=1, a_2=1, a_3=4,a_4=2,a_5=8$, so $a_2*a_3$ and $a_4*a_5$ are perfect squares.
Then we have to prove that if we have $a_(2n-1)*a_(2n)$ is a perfect square, then we have $a_(2n)+a_(2n+1)$ is a perfect square.
I tried to replace the notation and process it, but got nothing useful.
Hope one of you can help me! Thanks!

Hint: List out like the first 20 values, make a guess for what $a_{2n}$ is, (and hence what $ \sqrt{ a_{2n} a_{2n+1}}$). Then prove $a_{2n}$ by induction, which is much easier than what you're suggesting.

What you need to show is that if $a_{2n} a_{2n+1}$ is a perfect square, the same happens with $a_{2n+2} a_{2n+3}$.

Hint: List out like the first 20 values, and make some conjectures.
Claim: $a_{2n} = n$.
Corollary: $a_{2n+1} = \lfloor \frac{ (2n)^2 } { n } \rfloor = 4n$. So $ \sqrt{ a_{2n} a_{2n+1} } = 2n$ as desired.
Proof of claim: Left to the reader to prove by induction.
We already showed $a_{2n+1} = 4n$, so just verify that $a_{2n+2} = n+1$.
